# How do you get skins in agar.io

Tags: agar.io

How do you get skins in agar.io

Answer (score 0):

To set your skin, you need to name yourself as one on [this list found on agarioguide.com](http://www.agarioguide.com/skins/)

If I wanted the Earth skin, I would name myself `Earth`.